# Where on Earth are the Visual Studio 2010 MFC build scripts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

Does anyone know where the Visual Studio 2010 (Service Pack 1 to be specific) build scripts are (I assume they're .vcxprojs these days, but can find neither these of .mak's).

I urgently need to build a instrumented set of release mode MFC DLLs that use the same coupling as the standard parts (i.e. these need to be extention DLLs - just pulling the MFC sources directly into the project is not going to hack it).

Any help pointers to the build scripts would be super helpful.

Comment: MS no longer ships the MFC makefiles in Visual Studio starting with VS 2010.

Comment: Hi Michael, yeah that's certainly what it looks like. Do you know *why* there was this change of policy? I can't find anything official from MS relating to this blanket pulling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your need. Maybe you simply need to use MFC in a static lib configuration?
Try 'Use MFC in a Static Library' on project settings.

If you are writing a dll maybe this help:
[Regular DLLs Statically Linked to MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The need is I want to change the way MFC reports certain kinds of errors, specifically I want to replace the dialog that pops up when a Improper Argument is encountered and replace it with a implementation that logs the callstack at that point. I want to be able to swap in and out these DLLs.